In aws glue job, how to use custom library?
I'm using Glue job Spark script.
I already made a Python code in SageMaker. In SageMaker, I used custom library folder. I use the folder like '''from A import B''' A is folder name and B is the def function in A.
I want to use this in Glue.
I found some docs, some docs said we should use egg, zip. but not sure exactly how can I do.

You can zip the custom library/package which you have created along with the code and pass the zip file as Glue Job configuration. Additionally you can specify the libraries you want to use in addition to the in built libraries provided by AWS Glue.
For more information please refer to the below documentation provided by AWS Folks:
Using python libraries in AWS Glue
Will look forward to hear on how it goes.
